# MooTools and Joomla, how does it work?

Tags: joomla, mootools

I've heard that mootools is installed with Joomla and you can use it from within any extension you build without having to include it again, is that correct?

I've been learning some JQuery and i wanted to build a module with it but now that mootools is included i'd rather do it with it. Is there a good tutorial on using mootools inside joomla modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware :
Joomla, up to 1.5.18 version, is Mootools 1.1.x based.

It is announced that next 1.5.X version will be Moo 1.2 based.

Release due July 15th 2010.

Joomla Beta(x) 1.6 is Moo 1.2 based though.

Magic to include your JS script within joomla, be it module or component:

```
<?php 
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument(); 
$doc->addStyleSheet("js/style.css"); 
$doc->addScript("js/script.js"); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these:
[Joomla! Docs - Using Mootools](http://docs.joomla.org/Beginners#Using_Mootools)